# Wordpress Option Tree plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have define an option in theme option for option tree plugin.

Option id is `banner_list`, the type is `list item`.

I do not know how to retrieve the option on my theme.

I typed

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'ot_get_option' ) ) {

    $banner_list = ot_get_option( 'banner_list' );

}
 echo $banner_list; ?>
```

,

but the output is `array`.

How should I write the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what exactly you are looking for concerning your plugin for wordpress. What I do know, is that the variable you're trying to echo is in fact an array.

I you want to know the array values your array is holding I'd suggest trying:

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r($banner_list); ?>
</pre>
```

This should give you an overview of the keys your array is holding as well as the values of those keys. After that you can either echo them out out individually or in a foreach loop.

More information concerning arrays and/or loops:

- http://www.tizag.com/phpT/arrays.php
- http://www.tizag.com/phpT/foreach.php
- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Hope this will help you in the right direction.

All the best and happy holidays!

Jesper

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution.

Comment: No problem :) Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer if it was of any help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy! Here is the solution:

```
<?php 
$banner_list  = get_option_tree( 'banner_list ', '', false );
?>
```

If you need to retrieve data from custom meta boxes, use below code:

```
<?php 
$header_image= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_header_image', true);
?>
```